# Create convenience Initializer on subclass that calls failable Initializer

Tags: ios, swift

Tried many variations of the derivation below but none work.

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit


class test:SCNScene{
    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    convenience init? (i:UIViewController){
        self.init(named:"") //Compile Error:use of self delegating initializer before self.init is called
    }

}
```

According to [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), rule 2 of initialization, shouldn't init?(named:String) convenience failable Initializer be available after implement the 2 designated Initializer? What am i getting wrong?

Comment: Rule 2 states "A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class." - your class doesn't define `init?(named:String)`

Comment: The rule i was referring is on "Automatic Initializer Inheritance" topic:
"If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers."

Comment: Yes, the superclass initialisers are available to you but that doesn't mean you can ignore the rule I quoted - you must call a non-convenience initialiser from your class

Comment: ok, so how to implement `init?(named:String)` at test class?
 `init?(named:String)` is a convenience initializer and there is no designated initializer that accepts the file not even there is a way to load after `self.init()`

Comment: You need to call `self.init()` before your call to `self.init(named:"")` as the error message says

Comment: Had the wrong idea that the second time would reinitialize the object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64661/discussion-between-paulw11-and-byteartisan).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The initialiser delegation rule #2 states

> A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same
>   class.

Your class doesn't define init?(named:String), so it will call superclass initialiser (which you do have access to under the other rule #2 you were referring to), but this won't satisfy the requirement to call a non-convenience initialiser from your class.

You can simply call `self.init` before calling the superclass initialiser.

```
convenience init? (i:UIViewController){
        self.init()
        self.init(named:"") 
}
```